# Iframe request come from client or intermediate server?

Tags: iframe, firewall

So, a Client connects to Server A, which then creates an iframe pointed at Server B. The Client submits a request through the iframe to Server B. Does Server B see the request as coming from the Client or from Server A?

Application: I have two services running on one machine, let's say one on port 443 and one on port 9090. Port 9090 is closed at the firewall, but it can be accessed from other services on the host machine. If I host a page on 443 with an iframe directed at port 9090, will that service see that request as coming from the host machine and send the data, or from the external client and drop the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server B will see the request coming from the client browser not from server A.

Generally Iframes are requesting its URL from the client browser.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to make the request from the server A side?